# How to divde two rows from different Dataframes in Python pandas which contain string and float.

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 dataframes I need to divide the value from 2 data frame which divide contain string and float the division should avoid the string and only do the division on float.

> DF1

```
       Col1     Val11   Val12
    0  A        1       9
    1  B        3       1
    2  C        5       4
    3  D        1       3
    4  E        7       6
```

> DF2

```
       Col2    Val21    Val22
    0  A       20       19
    1  B       35       11
    2  C       46       42
    3  D       31       53
    4  E       28       55
```

I wrote the below line of code

```
df2.iloc['Percent'] = df1.iloc[4]/df2.iloc[4]
```

But I get the below error message.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Final DF should look like this

```
       Col2    Val21    Val22
    0  A       20       19
    1  B       35       11
    2  C       46       42
    3  D       31       53
    4  E       28       55
               0.25     0.10
```

Thanks and Advance for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need get all string columns to index by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then divide:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('Col2')
df2.loc['Percent'] = df1.set_index('Col1').iloc[4].values / df2.iloc[4]
print (df2)

         Val21      Val22
Col2                     
A        20.00  19.000000
B        35.00  11.000000
C        46.00  42.000000
D        31.00  53.000000
E        28.00  55.000000
Percent   0.25   0.109091
```

If there is multiple string columns use `subsets` of columns for divide and also add subset to output:

```
df2.loc['Percent'] = df1[['Val11','Val12']].iloc[4].values /  df2[['Val21','Val22']].iloc[4]
print (df2)
        Col2  Val21      Val22
0          A  20.00  19.000000
1          B  35.00  11.000000
2          C  46.00  42.000000
3          D  31.00  53.000000
4          E  28.00  55.000000
Percent  NaN   0.25   0.109091
```

More generic solution:

```
str_cols1 = ['Col1']
str_cols2 = ['Col2']
df2.loc['Percent'] = df1.drop(str_cols1, axis=1).iloc[4].values /
                     df2.drop(str_cols2, axis=1).iloc[4]
print (df2)
        Col2  Val21      Val22
0          A  20.00  19.000000
1          B  35.00  11.000000
2          C  46.00  42.000000
3          D  31.00  53.000000
4          E  28.00  55.000000
Percent  NaN   0.25   0.109091
```

And better solution with [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df2.loc['Percent'] = df1.select_dtypes(['number']).iloc[4].values /
                     df2.select_dtypes(['number']).iloc[4]
print (df2)
        Col2  Val21      Val22
0          A  20.00  19.000000
1          B  35.00  11.000000
2          C  46.00  42.000000
3          D  31.00  53.000000
4          E  28.00  55.000000
Percent  NaN   0.25   0.109091
```

EDIT by comment:

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) for replace non numeric values to `NaN`:

```
df1_numeric = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
df2_numeric = df2.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

df2.loc['Percent'] = df1_numeric.iloc[4].values / df2_numeric.iloc[4]
print (df2)
        Col2  Val21     Val22
0          A  20.00        19
1          B  35.00         a
2          C  46.00        42
3          D  31.00        53
4          E  28.00        55
Percent  NaN   0.25  0.109091
```

Comment: Since this was an example I used only one string column. If I have multiple string columns will this solutions work ?

Comment: I add another solution, please check it.

Comment: Just in case the column names are too many it may not be feasible to write all can there be a generic solution ?

Comment: Say 3 string Columns and 14 numeric Columns

Comment: Please check last edit. Simply remove string columns and then divide.

Comment: Yes it also work thank you as some string cols are in between the values.

Comment: This string values between numeric values are in multiple columns?

Comment: 3 columns 2 at start and one is second last

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
df2.loc['Percent'] = df1.iloc[4, 1:] / df2.iloc[4, 1:]
```

Comment: Yes its also working. Thank you just one doubt what is the significance of 1: in the code.

Comment: Does it put the data in the correct columns though? I was not 100% sure of this answer ... The 1's are there to select columns from #1 to the end (i.e. skip the first one which is a string - that is what caused your problem)

Comment: oh..okay let me verify